# How to edit an entry inside View Model / Repository with Live Data

Tags: java, android, repository, viewmodel, android-livedata

Maybe I'm misunderstanding this all, but how do you edit data using Live Data/View Model/Repository? I see how query all the data, delete an entry, but I want to edit a particular field.

For example, I have 3 things I'm tracking. Date, Time, and Category.I need to be able to change what the category is.

I tried doing something like this in one of my activities:

```
        budgetViewModel.getAllEntries().observe(this, new Observer<List<BudgetEntry>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<BudgetEntry> budgetEntries) {


                Log.i(TAG, "2nd Observer is going off");

                if (manualUpdate == 1) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "MANUAL UPDATE");

                    budgetEntries.get(0).setCategory(updatedCategory);
                    manualUpdate = 0;

                    Log.i(TAG, "Budget Entries: " + budgetEntries.get(0).getCategory());
                }

                else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "No change");
                }


            }
        });
    }

    }
```

But it doesn't change it permanently. Only for this instance I guess because the Log shows I changed the category, but when I reload the app or check another activity, it still shows the prior data.

I can't find any tutorials on this so any guidance would be most appreciated!

New View Model Changes. I get error cannot create instance of class:

public class BudgetViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

```
private BudgetRepository budgetRepository;

//private LiveData<List<BudgetEntry>> allEntries;

LiveData<List<BudgetEntry>> _allEntries = budgetRepository.getAllEntries();
LiveData<List<BudgetEntry>> allEntries = Transformations.map(_allEntries, new Function<List<BudgetEntry>, List<BudgetEntry>>() {
    @Override
    public List<BudgetEntry> apply(List<BudgetEntry> input) {
        return input;
    }
});



public BudgetViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    budgetRepository = new BudgetRepository(application);
    //allEntries = budgetRepository.getAllEntries();


}

public void insert (BudgetEntry budgetEntry) {
    budgetRepository.insert(budgetEntry);
}


public void delete (BudgetEntry budgetEntry) {
    budgetRepository.delete(budgetEntry);
}

public void deleteAllEntries () {
    budgetRepository.deleteAllEntries();
}

public LiveData<List<BudgetEntry>> getAllEntries() {
    return _allEntries;
}

public LiveData<Integer> getCount() {
    return budgetRepository.getCount();
}
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally figured it out, whoo hoo! I couldn't get the Transformation answer to work so I started researching how to use @Update. I wanted to share in case this help someone in the future, because this one took me weeks. :)

I was tracking 3 things in my model. Category, Date, Time. My goal was to be able to change ALL category names that matched a particular string to a new string.

First you need to name your column in your Model:

@ColumnInfo(name="CATEGORY")
private String category;

Then you need to create a SQL query in your DAO that finds and UPDATES the old category with the new category:

```
@Query("UPDATE entry SET CATEGORY = :newcategory WHERE category = :oldcategory")
void updateColumn(String newcategory, String oldcategory);
```

This basically says find all categories that match a string, and update them to your new string.

Now you need to make your methods in your View Model and Repository.

We will start with the Repository to make an Async Task. First I need to bundle my old category and new category together so I'll make a class in the Repository.

```
private static class ParamsSend {
    String newCategory;
    String oldCategory;

    ParamsSend(String newCategory, String oldCategory) {
        this.newCategory = newCategory;
        this.oldCategory = oldCategory;
    }
}
```

Then I'll create an Async Task passing those parameters.

private static class UpdateColumnAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ParamsSend, Void, Void> {
private BudgetDao budgetDao;

```
    private UpdateColumnAsyncTask(BudgetDao budgetDao) {
        this.budgetDao = budgetDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(ParamsSend... paramsSends) {
        String newCategory = paramsSends[0].newCategory;
        String oldCategory = paramsSends[0].oldCategory;
        budgetDao.updateColumn(newCategory, oldCategory);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then create the method to call the Async Task:

```
public void updateColumn(String newCategory, String oldCategory) {

    ParamsSend paramsSend  = new ParamsSend(newCategory, oldCategory);
    new UpdateColumnAsyncTask(budgetDao).execute(paramsSend);
}
```

Then we will go to the ViewModel and create a method to run the Async Task in the Repoository:

```
public void updateColumn(String newCategory, String oldCategory) {
    budgetRepository.updateColumn(newCategory, oldCategory);
```

Lastly we'll update it in our activity:

```
         budgetViewModel.updateColumn(updatedCategory, oldCategory);
```

Good luck all, I hope this helps! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Transformations.map](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations) function in your ViewModel for this.

> Applies the given function on the main thread to each value emitted by source LiveData and returns LiveData, which emits resulting values. 
>  
>  The given function func will be executed on the main thread.

**Kotlin**

```kotlin
import androidx.lifecycle.*

class YourViewModel : ViewModel() {
  private val _allEntries: LiveData<List<BudgetEntry>> = budgetRepository.getAllEntries()
  val allEntries: LiveData<List<BudgetEntry>> = Transformations.map(_allEntries) { list: List<BudgetEntry> ->
    list.map { budgetEntry ->
       budgetEntry.setCategory(updatedCategorya)
    }
  }
}
```

**Java**

```java
import androidx.lifecycle.*;

class YourViewModel extends ViewModel {
  private final LiveData<List<BudgetEntry>> _allEntries = budgetRepository.getAllEntries();
  final LiveData<List<BudgetEntry>> allEntries = Transformations.map(_allEntries, new Function<List<BudgetEntry>, List<BudgetEntry>>() {
        @Override
        public List<BudgetEntry> apply(List<BudgetEntry> input) {
            // do the mapping for each budgetEntry
            return // mapped list
        }
    });
}
```

Now you can observe `allEntries` as usual. The `map` functions take care of updating the LiveData.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I tried implementing what you mentioned and I get a "Cannot create instance of a class". I updated my question to show what my view model looks like now. Do you have any advice for that? Thank you!

Comment: Which instance, which class can not be created? And where exactly? Otherwise I can just guess.

Comment: Cannot create an instance of class android.example.com.budgetkeeper.Models.BudgetViewModel, then later it says:Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'androidx.lifecycle.LiveData android.example.com.budgetkeeper.Database.BudgetRepository.getAllEntries()' on a null object reference .  I think it has to do with not calling allEntries in the constructor. My view model is in the main question above if that helps. Thanks again!

Comment: Your `BudgetRepository` is null, because you are accessing the repository (above the constructor) `budgetRepository.getAllEntries();` before you are creating it in your constructor below. You can do the assignment for the LiveData also in the constructor, after creating the Repository.